# Calculating the distance between 2 Points in 2D and 3D

Tags: java, math, 3d

I'm just trying to solve a very simple problem, but I have some minor isses. Hope you can help out a beginner real quick ;)

I have 2 classes 'Point' and 'Point3D' which look like that:

```
public class Point {
    protected double x;
    protected double y;

    Point(double xCoord, double yCoord){
        this.x = xCoord;
        this.y = yCoord;
    }

    public double getX(){
        return x;
    }

    public double getY(){
        return y;
    }

    public static double distance(Point a, Point b)
    {
        double dx = a.x - b.x;
        double dy = a.y - b.y;
        return Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Point p1 = new Point(2,2);
        Point p2 = new Point(5,6);
        System.out.println("Distance between them is " + Point.distance(p1, p2));
    }
}
```

And this:

```
public class Point3D extends Point {
    protected double z;

    Point3D(double x, double y, double zCoord){
        super(x, y);
        this.z = zCoord;
    }

    public double getZ(){
        return z;
    }

    public static double distance(Point p1, Point p2){
        double dx = p1.x - p2.x;
        double dy = p1.y - p2.y;
        double dz = p1.z - p2.z;
        return Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy + dz *dz);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Point3D p1 = new Point3D(-4,2,5);
        Point3D p2 = new Point3D(1,3,-2);
        System.out.println("Distance between them is " + Point3D.distance(p1, p2));
    }
}
```

My problem now is the following: 
If I keep my code like this, my Eclipse is saying that 'z cannot resolved into a field' and as a possible solution I should create it in my class 'Point'.
After doing that the class 'Point3D' compiles but doesn't calculate the right answer..

Greetings,

Comment: `Point` -> `Point3D` (voting to close as a typo).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the signature of the Point3D distance method to:

```
public static double distance(Point3D p1, Point3D p2){
```

You only had `Point` types for the arguments, which don't have a `z`.

Comment: god damnit... To be honest I was looking at that code for like 30 Minutes and couldn't figure that out.. Thanks a lot sir